# Translation/Colloquial Equivalents: “There's More Than One Way To Skin A Cat”

Tags: translation, equivalent-phrase

I've come across a few, very poor, literal translations for the English, “there's more than one way to skin a cat”:

> 给猫剥皮不止有一种方法

> （谚）达到目的的方法不止一种

> 到达目标的设施多得很。

- What colloquial equivalents exist for this phrase? (which basically means: **there's more than one way to do something**)

Comment: "All roads lead to Rome", 条条大路通罗马, seems more common.

Comment: Well, it's not necessarily every way that will get the job done, though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

各施各法

Each person does (it) his own way. It comes from a longer phrase:

八仙過海，各施各法

Which is about eight fairies in Chinese mythology. When they needed to cross the ocean, each did it his/her own way.

Comment: sounds very Sinatra-esque.

Comment: Actually it was Paul Anka who wrote the lyrics, but sure, since Sinatra popularized it :)

Comment: It should be "八仙過海, 各顯神通"

Comment: 八仙過海, 各顯神通 is also correct as is 八仙過海，各施各法. What an apt way to illustrate "There is more than one way to skin a cat."

Comment: Can it also be `八仙過海,各施其法`? That's the version I am familiar with.

Comment: @ThomasHsieh  Well, I personally am not familiar with this particular one, but it's easily understood, so why not? As the saying goes, there is more than one way ....

Answer (score 2):

条条大路通罗马

I don't know if there is something as bloody as "skin a cat" in Chinese.

Comment: To "skin" a cat is to remove its fur.

To "skin" a catfish (鯰魚) is to remove its skin as preparation for dish.

Answer (score 2):

别在一颗树上吊死

You do not have to hang on just this one tree.

Comment: 请比较 iciba： macabre； 可怕的； 以死亡为主题的； 令人毛骨悚然的  He takes a macabre interest in graveyards.
    他那么留意墓地,令人毛骨悚然.4. Police have made a macabre discovery.
    警方有一个令人毛骨悚然的发现。

Comment: @S.Rhee ?????????????

Comment: some users might view using ＂hanging oneself from a tree＂ as a somewhat macabre way of rendering the expression into Chinese，很可能有一些使用者觉得用＂在一颗树上吊死＂来翻译讨论中的英文说法有点太可怕。Chinese speakers，however may not feel that way，in particular since iciba translates 不要在一棵树上吊死 as
＂don't put all your eggs in one basket＂
sample sentence：1.The key word here is diversify; don't put all your eggs in one basket.
这里的关键词是多样性；不要在一棵树上吊死。

另外从新闻报道来看吊死／缢死／自缢／缢颈在中国好像很受欢迎。

Comment: @S.Rhee 另外从新闻报道来看吊死／缢死／自缢／缢颈在中国好像很受欢迎。[来源请求]

Comment: 这可能有点夸张，只是看起来而已。不过似乎是自杀最流行的形式。

Comment: This is not really adding anything to the answer, to be honest.

Comment: @S.Rhee, In Chinese, this statement has nothing to do with suicide. If you talk to 100 native Chinese, 99 of them do not find it negative. Thank you for comments.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the simplest way to say it, colloquially and informally, is
"辦法多得是"
"總有辦法的"

If you are speaking in Cantonese, then these two phrases mean exactly what you intend to say:
"實有計既" or "唔止一條路"

A less direct yet more formal translation is:
辦法總比困難多

Or a logical inversion could be:
不可能解決不了

Answer (score -2):

How about this I found: 不要因为不能马上成为某事物的专家而失望.

Or this: 有多于一种的方式

Or this:     达到目的的办法多得很。

Comment: Don't be disappointed if you can't immediately be an expert of something.....

Comment: Er, that's what the saying means, if at first you don't succeed ...

Comment: I'm not sure where you learned your English, but it doesn't mean that. http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/there%27s+more+than+one+way+to+skin+a+cat "You can always find more than one way to do something." | "something that you say which means that there are several possible ways of achieving something"

Comment: Not sure whether you understand English, this is said when one way of doing something does not come to fruition for whatever reason. "Do not worry, there is ..